# Should one prefer static or local variables for passing a variable from main() to a self-contained modular function in another .c file?

Tags: c

What would be the most efficient way to pass a variable from main() to a function in another .c file? The function from the .c file would encapsulate all the other functions from the same file and pass the data onto them.
The concern I have with local variables is that they would have to be carried along through several layers of function arguments in the worst case scenario.

So I made a benchmark:

**static.h**

```
#ifndef SSSSTATIC
#define SSSSTATIC

#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double change_static_variable(int magic);
double change_global_variable(int magic);
double change_local_variable(int magic, unsigned long int *local_variable);
void do_the_calculations(unsigned long int *local_variable);

#endif
```

**static.c**

```
#include "static.h"

#define BIG_LOOPS   100
#define LOOPS       10000
#define STATIC_V    0
#define GLOBAL_V    1
#define LOCAL_V     2


extern unsigned long int global_variable;
extern int magic_variable;
static unsigned long int static_variable = 0;

double change_static_variable(int magic) {
    int i;
    clock_t start, end;
    start = clock();
    for (i = 0; i < LOOPS; i++) {
        static_variable += magic;
    }
    end = clock();
    return (double)(end - start);
}

double change_global_variable(int magic) {
    int i;
    clock_t start, end;
    start = clock();
    for (i = 0; i < LOOPS; i++) {
        global_variable += magic;
    }
    end = clock();
    return (double)(end - start);
}

double change_local_variable(int magic, unsigned long int *local_variable) {
    int i;
    clock_t start, end;
    start = clock();
    for (i = 0; i < LOOPS; i++) {
        *local_variable += magic;
    }
    end = clock();
    return (double)(end - start);
}

void do_the_calculations(unsigned long int *local_variable) {
    double times[3][BIG_LOOPS];
    int i;
    unsigned long int reset_value = global_variable;
    static_variable = reset_value;      /* make all same starting number */

    for (i = 0; i < BIG_LOOPS; i++) {
        times[STATIC_V][i] = change_static_variable(magic_variable);
        times[GLOBAL_V][i] = change_global_variable(magic_variable);
        times[LOCAL_V][i] = change_local_variable(magic_variable, local_variable);
        magic_variable++;
        static_variable = reset_value;
        global_variable = reset_value;
        *local_variable = reset_value;
    }

    printf("CLOCKS x%d NEEDED FOR:\n\n\tSTATIC\tGLOBAL\tLOCAL\n\n", LOOPS);
    for (i = 0; i < BIG_LOOPS; i++) {
        printf("\t%.0f\t%.0f\t%.0f\n", times[STATIC_V][i], times[GLOBAL_V][i], times[LOCAL_V][i]);

        /* USE [0] to get totals */
        times[STATIC_V][0] += times[STATIC_V][i];
        times[GLOBAL_V][0] += times[GLOBAL_V][i];
        times[LOCAL_V][0] += times[LOCAL_V][i];
    }
    printf("\n\tSTATIC\tGLOBAL\tLOCAL\n");
    printf("TOTAL:\t%.0f\t%.0f\t%.0f\n", times[STATIC_V][0], times[GLOBAL_V][0], times[LOCAL_V][0]);
    printf("AVG:\t%.0f\t%.0f\t%.0f\n", (times[STATIC_V][0] / BIG_LOOPS), (times[GLOBAL_V][0] / BIG_LOOPS), (times[LOCAL_V][0] / BIG_LOOPS));
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include "static.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

int global_variable;
int magic_variable;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unsigned long int local_variable;

    if (argc == 3) {
        global_variable = atoi(argv[1]);
        local_variable = global_variable;
        magic_variable = atoi(argv[2]);

        do_the_calculations(&local_variable);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compile with: `gcc -o output main.c static.c`
Run with 2 int args `./output 2 3`

First arg is starting value of all the variables so they are on the same level.
Second arg is a magic number to surprise the functions, but still keep any possible optimizations.
Used unsigned to make them overflowable, long to fit more numbers, and the vars are reset after every set of loops, so it doesn't go too big.

RESULTS:
Static and local basically similar. One wins one time, other another. But global is definitely the loser by about 10%.

So what would be the optimal solution?

Comment: To do performance tests enable optimizations: `gcc -O2 ....`

Comment: People sometimes get a bit dogmatic about using "global" variables to store or exchange program state.  Such people will tell you flatly that global variable use is unequivocally Bad Bad Bad.  As with most things, the reality is more nuanced.  Nevertheless, using file-scope variables to track or exchange data tends to produce problems in programs of any complexity.  Giving the variables internal linkage helps only a little with that.  Performance is not really the issue to focus on here (though indeed I don't expect a significant performance difference).